# Blender > Unity - How do I set a Mesh's Root Bone?

Tags: mesh, armature, export, unity, parent

When I export my skinned character from Blender to Unity all skinned meshes of that character have the wrong transform assigned in their Root Bone transform field.

**Why is that bad?** Whatever you assign as the Root Bone in a skinned mesh acts as a parent to the mesh's bounding box. If the bounding box is offscreen, the mesh doesn't get rendered. So if the bounding box has the wrong parent it's possible that the mesh looks like it's on screen while it's bounding box isn't, resulting in the mesh not being rendered. Which obviously we don't want. That's why the Root Bone should ideally be a bone close to the mesh or a bone the mesh has the most weights on.

**Example:**
Let's look at the character's hair for example. The hair is a single mesh. All vertices of the hair are skinned to the head bone only, nothing else.

[image: Vertex Groups of Hair mesh].

In Unity the root bone field should have the head bone assigned (as that's the only bone the vertices are skinned to) but for some reason it's the character's root bone.

[image: Wrongly assigned Root Bone in Unity]

**Setup:** The character is divided into two groups: A mesh parent with all the separate meshes that make up the character and an armature. I have an additional Root Bone in case I intend to use Root Motion later.

[image: Character hierarchy (Unity)]

This is mostly the same in blender.

[image: Character hierarchy (Blender)]

**Export settings:** I exported the character as an FBX from Blender 3.4 using the following settings:

[image]

I tinkered around with different settings (Only Deform Bones, ArmatureFBXNodes) without any different results.

Looking at other projects I did in the past where I used Maya I can see that the Root Bone field has been assigned properly back then (not the same character). I have no idea what I did different in Maya.

I know I can manually change the Root Bone of a skinned mesh but since there will be a lot of characters it would be a lot of unneccessary work to fix each mesh manually.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Renaming the Root bone in the hierarchy doesn't do anything. The same renamed bone will still get used as the Root Bone field in skinned meshes.
- Deleting the Root bone in the hierarchy doesn't fix it either, the skinned meshes just take the next bone in the hierarchy (now hips).
- Trying out different export settings didn't seem to have an impact.

I hope someone knows something. I'd really appreciate any input. Thanks!